# Eclipse doesn't recognize Scala source directory

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I installed Maven Scala support from http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/, and the Scala IDE plugin using the Eclipse Marketplace. I can build the project using the command line with `mvn compile`. Eclipse highlights Scala code nicely, and if I import the project it correctly recognizes its Scala Nature. But it doesn't recognize `src/main/scala` as source folder, and doesn't build the project.

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.examples.scala</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-examples</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong? Something wrong with the pom?

As a workaround, I manually set `src/main/scala` as source folder (right-click, **Build Path | Use as Source Folder**). But that's not great, I'd like to find the real solution, so that the project would be correctly setup when doing a clean import as a Maven project.

**UPDATE**

Simply adding the `add-source` goal + update Maven project did the trick:

```xml
<goals>
    <goal>add-source</goal>
    <goal>compile</goal>
    <goal>testCompile</goal>
</goals>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to `java-maven-plugin`, there is a `addSource` goal that let you defines source and test directories. You can this for example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
                <configuration>
                   <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                    <testSourceDir>src/main/test</testSourceDir>
                 </configuration>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I found the documentation in this [link](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html)

Comment: Thanks! Simply adding the `add-source` goal did the trick (in front of `compile` and `testCompile`, see my update above), slightly simpler than your example (I recommend to update your post).

Answer (score 1):

Copy-paste snippet for the latest plugin version:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <executions>
         <execution>
              <goals>
                   <goal>add-source</goal>
                   <goal>compile</goal>
                   <goal>testCompile</goal>
              </goals>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Reference: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/ + @Dimitri answer